# What is the behaviour of CometD implementation that use a synchronous buffer when the buffer is empty?

Tags: java, cometd

CometD 3.1.4 java implementation uses a buffer to keep track of the incoming message and this buffer has a default size of 2MB. When restarting from a disconnection, spikes can occur and you can exceed the limit.

What behaviour does the library have? Bytes are lost and if subsequent notifications from the server side are received they can be processed ?

Answer (score 1):

The client-side buffering limit can be configured as explained [here](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_client_transports_configuration).

However, I recommend that you review your logic, as sending MiBs of messages to the client is typically not recommended, as the client may take a long while to process them all.
Also, if the messages are few but with large data, you may want to setup things so that the client gets a CometD message with a download URI to be downloaded on the side, rather than sending the data in the CometD messages.

Having said that, you can write a [server-side extension](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_extensions) to, for example, discard old messages so that you don't send MiBs of data in case of reconnections.

The [message acknowledgment](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_extensions_acknowledge) extension guarantees server-to-client delivery, so -- provided you don't exceed the client-side receive buffer -- you can guarantee that queued messages are delivered to clients.

You may need a combination of things that is specific to your application.
You may need a [server-side listener](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_concepts_listeners_server) to control the size of the message queue, the acknowledgment extension to guarantee delivery, and maybe a larger client-side buffer.

This is not done by default by CometD because everybody wants a different solution: some want to fail the session, some want to discard all messages, some want to keep only the last N, etc.

CometD provides you with the hooks you need to implement your logic.

Comment: I do not control the server, just the client. Do you confirm that the client will lose notifications if the buffer size is too small?

Comment: The client will lose messages if the server sends enormous messages or an enormous amount of messages that exceed the configured max message size. This happens with any transport, e.g. browsers have a limit for WebSocket messages that is few KiB (not MiB like your case). You need to contact the server application provider to ask them to send smaller batches. If you use HTTP transports, you may configure a very large max message size on the client.